# Merge Google Cloud Logs lines in logs Explorer

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have 2 logs coming from 2 sources. One from an Api pod and one from an ingress controller pod.

I want to merge both of those logs together in one line, since both of them have the same traceID field.

But I'm not sure if I can do it from the Gcloud Log Viewer UI ? any ideas or leads on how to do it ?[image]

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it in log explorer. But you can export your logs to BigQuery and deduplicate the logs entry with a SQL query, and get only the relevant data that you want, perform analysis and aggregation.

Comment: Does this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/combining-correlated-log-lines-in-google-stackdriver-dd23284aeb29) help? https://medium.com/google-cloud/combining-correlated-log-lines-in-google-stackdriver-dd23284aeb29